# Bigquery cannot load all data when streaming

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi i am streaming data from my apps to Bigquery by C++.
Thing got okay and the all are connectable, but the problem is the log file said there's 665 in streaming buffers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktln8.png)

However, final records in the table is just 4. Does anyone know to solve this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUtWW.png)

Comment: my code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1scVnjOE8wvWFN3v_WDkPwdk4pj4qsoHNz4IcN7IwMBM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for your great support. We found out that the issue happen because in the code we wrote, "insertId" should be unique, otherwise, BQ will deduplicate row with similar insertID. In the code, it happened since we set insertID = 'rowdetail' only. After changing it to time inserted (ddmmyyhhmmss), the pipeline run normally.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJsPR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJsPR.png) Hope it helpful for you and everyone

Answer (score 0):

"Estimated rows" are only an estimate.

Streaming data in BigQuery is available in real-time (though table copy commands can take up to 90 minutes). I recommend reading [this article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability) for more information.

It sounds like you think you're losing data. That's not likely. I recommend checking what you believe is being inserted versus what's actually landing in the table.

Comment: Hi Brad, thank you for your comment. We retest the streaming several time and wait after a day to check, the result is the same. Not sure whether it's limit of Bigquery?

Comment: When you say you retest, do you mean you're checking what should go in versus what shows up? Are you losing data? It's impossible to troubleshoot without knowing this.

Comment: Retest mean we run the code again and again. and yes we check the log webhook return vs Bigquery table. still 4 vs 665 several time

Comment: Is your code actually inserting 665 records? I suspect it's only inserting 4. That's my question: are you losing records?